# what project will use websocket instead of webrtc?

Tags: html, websocket, webrtc

my very little knowledge.

- websocket: server control the connections, messages flow between clients and server.
- webrtc: server control the connections, messages flow between clients and clients.

Am I understand right?

For example I want to build a text chatting application between a group of peoples.
What if I need to logging (capture) the messages between clients, save to the server, I must use websocket?

Comment: For this particular implementation where you say that you would like the chat to be stored on a server, I would say that websockets is the way to go. If skipping the centralized logging at server, webRTC is a good option (if only looking at the technical bit, browser support for websockets is much more common than WebRTC)

Answer (score 1):

Humm ... no.

With WebRTC it is possible establish the communication between peers only using the server for signaling peer information before start. This enables for example, direct video and audio communication as long the peer communication is possible.

In your chat example, you would use websockets to establish a persistent full duplex connection to the sever that manages the chat rooms and broadcast the messages to all the other room participants. Also, you may provide a "direct chat" option, where users may exchange messages directly and even have a voice/video chat using WebRTC.

Again, the peer communication depends on the network conditions between them, for example if one of them is using NAT traversal it would not be possible for the signaling server to figure out how to connect them, so a relay server should then be used (and therefore, it would not be peer communication).

Roughly, WebRTC enables peer communication through UDP, websockets use TCP. WebRTC tries to enable communication between peers (STUN), but may fallback to a relay server approach (TURN) if such communication is not possible.